# How to use a Kotlin extension function on a class?

Tags: android, function, class, kotlin, extension-function

I have a pretty short question about an extension function that would help clear some of my code. Basically I have some transformations on the hashCode of a class name and I want an extension function to do the transformations.

Example:

Getting the name hashCode: `StateA::class.java.name.hashCode()` where StateA is a simple class.

I want to the extension function like:

```
    fun Class<*>.transformName(): String {
       var hashString = this.javaClass.name.hashCode()

       //Do my stuff on that hashString

       return hashString
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I apply the extension function with `StateA.transformName()`, the function gives me an error with Unresolved Reference.

I tried various things like applying the function to `StateA::class` or having the hashString equal to `this::class.java.name.hashCode()` but nothing works. Any tips?

Comment: You've created extension on Class type and `StateA` is not a type of Class. `StateA::class.java` is a valid Class type object.

Comment: `StateA::class.java.transformName()` would work

Comment: I see now. Yes it does work. And the string in the function will be like `this.name.hashCode()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't *really* achieve the `StateA.transformName()` syntax, as `StateA` just on its own refers to the companion object inside that class. So to get that syntax, you'd need to have a companion object inside every class that you want to use this extension on.

What you can do in a very general way is get the `KClass` that describes your class first. This gives you an object (the `KClass` instance) that you can then call an extension on:

```
fun KClass<*>.transformName() {
    val clazz: Class<*> = this.java
    clazz.name.hashCode()
}

StateA::class.transformName()
```

Another approach, which is less verbose on the call site could be a generic function like this, where the `reified` keyword allows you to access the concrete class that was used as the generic type parameter inside the function:

```
inline fun <reified T> transformName() {
    val clazz: Class<*> = T::class.java
    clazz.name.hashCode()
}

transformName<StateA>()
```

Comment: Now I see. Thanks. I think all three solutions are good. I think I will come down to creating a companion object (like you said) in every class and use it the simple way like `StateA.transformName()`. I'll log some things to make sure it doesn't cause any problems but the other two solutions are also great in terms of code practice. Thank you a lot, sir!

Comment: Or maybe not. If I think more about it, the cleaner solution is your last one with the reified. I don't think it's actually a good practice to add some useless companion objects just for some function.

Comment: It's not a bad practice to add a companion object in a class to put extensions on it like that (it's why `kotlin.Boolean` has a companion, for example), but yes, it might be tedious to do it for several classes, only to let them be used with this one extension.